# android -> how to run python script as root?

Tags: android, python

How can I run a python script as root in Android ?
I made a simple python script and placed it in /data/data/py.test/pyshell.py
the content of pyshell.py is

```
import os
os.system('am start -d "http://www.stackoverflow.com"')
```

If I try the command "python /data/data/py.test/pyshell.py"
It should normally start the web-browser but it doesn't. I just get an message:
Starting: Intent {dat=http://www.stackoverflow.com}

But if I go to Terminal Emulator and write:

```
su
python /data/data/py.test/pyshell.py
```

I get root rights and the browser starts. So the problem must be with root.

How can I give "/data/data/py.test/pyshell.py" automatic/always root access.

Comment: You could make a bash script to run the file in sudo.

Comment: @debianplebian, sudo might require a password prompt. You could try doing something like `echo <cmd> | su`. That way it'd create a su shell and run the command in the shell. Actually, if sudo /does/ work, then you could also just do `sudo <cmd>` rather than sticking it in its own script.

Comment: @joshlf13 I think it would take a password either way, but we don't know what his application is, so there is no way to know how it should be done.

Comment: Maybe create a script and set suid? You could probably do that through some Java library so you wouldn't need to worry about password prompts.

Answer (score -1):

As this will execute Linux command enter

```
os.system("su")
```

If properly rooted you will get prompt.....